# jade - create multiple html elements

Tags: html, css, class, pug

I want to create multiple elements having the same class with jade. Is this possible?
It should be something like this:

```
3 times do
  insert div.className
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiple elements can share a single class without issue, just as in standard HTML. That's one of the underlying differences between a class and ID, though there is some other differentiation.

An easy way to do this is using a traditional JavaScript for-loop incorporated into your Jade template.

`- for(var x = 0;X < 3;x++)
  .nameOfClass`

or (obviously)

`- for(var x = 1;x <= 3;x++)
  .nameOfClass`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I searched for!